# Proper way to show popup data on a web page?

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have a list of items for which I want to show a couple of items, then a "more" button.  I would like the more button to show the new items in a popup box. There are many ways to make this work, but I'm trying to figure out what is the best practice.

Here is my approach. We use MooTools and Clientcide on our site:

Directly following the "more" button, I include a div that contains the content I want to put in the popup (the full list, including a duplication of those items that are visible by default), with a class that includes the style "display:none".

I attach an event to the more button that runs a script called "popupNext". popupNext takes the next element after the button (using getNext from mootools), and creates a new StickyWin (via Clientcide and stickywin.ui) with that element as its content. Then (and this is the part that feels especially hacky) it removes the class that includes the "display:none" style from the content element.

Finally, I use element.store() (from mooTools) to store the StickyWin (with the key "win") in the event element.  I neglected to mention above: when popupNext runs, it first checks via element.retrieve() whether there is an existing StickyWin, and shows it, if there is.

This all seems OK, I guess--the biggest disadvantage is page bloat--while I'm showing only first couple of elements of each list, there may be more that are loaded with each page but never seen.  But I'm curious whether there is some better, standard way of doing this. For example, I could reduce bloat by retrieving the elements via ajax, at the expense of slower response when a user wants to see the full list.

Answer (score 0):

Check out StickyWin.Ajax - it seems to be closer to what you need than the plain StickyWin.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. While I use StickyWin.Ajax in many places, I'm concerned enough about speed that I'd rather not use Ajax for these cases.